# What do you call person who create products or things?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call person who create products or things like cars, drones, airplanes, tables, chairs, etc. This person is someone who really does it, like cutting some material, measuring, uniting, welding, nailing, carving, drilling, painting, etc.

Comment: Anything from craftsman to assembly line worker. Things get built in a lot of different ways. Some people put in or paint a few parts in a complex mechanism, others build objects from start to finish.

Comment: They might be broadly classified as a “blue collar worker”

Comment: Mostly, they are called artisans or specifically carpenter  (*for tables, chairs, etc*), mechanic, technician etc.

Comment: In modern manufacturing, none of the things you listed are created by a single individual with a single role. Also, to improve the answers, you should probably give a sentence with a blank for the word you want.

Answer (score 2):

As a word that describes all of those things in *broad* terms, you could actually use the same word that's more commonly used for companies rather than individuals: [**manufacturer**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manufacturer):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : one that manufactures
>   // *especially* : an employer of workers in manufacturing

If you *create* products, then you are *manufacturing* them. You could be considered a manufacturer of those items.

But note that the dictionary definition itself stresses that the word is more commonly used for the employer of the workers, rather than for the workers themselves. (Even if applying it to an individual worker is, technically, correct.)

Rather than using the general term for an individual worker, we use a more specialized term that's based on the particular items being produced. If they make clothing, the workers are called *tailors*; if they make shoes, the workers are called *cobblers*; if they create books, the workers are called *authors*, and and so on.

---

Note, too, that I described each of the people as a [**worker**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worker), which could also be used if you want to emphasize the *labour* rather than the *product*:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>    **1 a** : one that works especially at manual or industrial labor or with a particular material
>   // a factory *worker*
>   —often used in combination
>   b : a member of the working class

Again, however, this typically rules out people involved in something other than manual labour. So, as with the word *manufacturer* being an odd choice to describe an author, it would be strange to describe an author as a *worker*, even though they do actually work at producing books.

Other words (such as *creator* and *producer*) will have the same problem, although to an even greater degree. For the most part, we simply don't use an umbrella word that applies equally to all of the people creating all of the things that have been mentioned. Instead, the creator of each type of thing is described with their own specific word.

Answer (score 2):

I would say **craftsman**. Or crafts worker. I believe that unlike tradesman, craftsman only includes trades that involve the production of physical goods.

From Merriam-Webster:

1 a worker who practices a trade or handicraft

2 one who creates or performs with skill or dexterity especially in the manual arts

From Oxford:
A worker skilled in a particular craft.

However, I'm not sure if this term excludes unskilled workers. Also it may have a connotation of a person who labors on their own to create things, rather than someone who works as part of a manufacturing process.

Answer (score 0):

I would say a Fabricator. He makes things with his hands or with the equipments he has..

Comment: Please add a source to support that.

Comment: Fabricator is a good suggestion, but citing a source would make this a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is [**tradesman**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tradesman).

The feminine equivalent  **tradeswoman** is sometimes used by trade union members, e.g. at the [B.C. Centre for Women in the Trades](https://www.bccwitt.ca/)

For a gender-neutral form, **trades worker** is probably the least worst of the alternatives.

**Edited to add:**

For the makers of small things, **craftsman** or **artisan** might be more appropriate.

In either case, the focus here is on the human being and their skills, not simply on the actions that the person is performing.  Same reason that we say *diner* as opposed to *eater*.

Comment: A tradesman (tradesperson) does not necessarily *create products or things* as required by the Op.  A tradesman may maintain, mend or repair things but not make them initially; a tradesman may *sell* goods.  Someone who paints my house or maintains my garden may be a tradesman - but he doesn't *create products or things*.

Comment: The expression “building trades” is commonly used to refer to the carpenters, masons, plumbers, electricians and other skilled workers that make buildings and other big things.

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't.  But Q. is "What do you call person **who create products or things**". I'm not denying that *some* tradesman make products - but also a lot of tradesmen *do not* make products. Therefore, I do not agree that 'tradesman' is a suitable answer for the Q..  Some 'people' make products - but also a lot of people *do not* make products.  You might just as well argue that 'people' is a suitable answer!